Discord.net/Discord.py record audio stream of user or whole channel
I am currently trying to record audio of a specific user or if not possible of the whole channel.
I started with Discord.py but was not successful. Currently the bot joins a channel when a specific user connects and should start recording. With python and C# I found old posts and github threads which supplied solutions to my problem but this solutions does not seem to work anymore. Did discord remove support for fetching the audio streams?
I would love to havet his feature but I do not find that much information. Playing audio is currently atleast in python no problem.
Coding:
private Task OnVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser? socketUser, SocketVoiceState before, SocketVoiceState after)
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Output($"Starting to handle user movements", Logger.LogType.Default);
            var currentChannel = after.VoiceChannel ?? before.VoiceChannel;
            if (currentChannel == null) return;
            var botUser = currentChannel.Guild.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IsBot);

            if (before.VoiceChannel == null && after.VoiceChannel != null) // If member joins a voice channel
            {
                var channel = after.VoiceChannel;

                try
                {
                    Logger.Output($"Connect bot to channel '{channel.Name}'", Logger.LogType.Default);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    _audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
                    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();


                    if (socketUser is not SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser) return;
                    if (socketGuildUser.AudioStream is not InputStream inputStream) return;

                    _ = Task.Run(() =>
                        ProcessAudioAsync(inputStream)
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Output($"Failed to connect and start recording: {e}", Logger.LogType.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Output($"Handling user movements failed! {e.Message}", Logger.LogType.Error);
        }
    });
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async Task ProcessAudioAsync(InputStream inputStream)
{
    // Create a new wave file writer to save the audio stream
    string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    string filename = Path.Combine(AudioRecordingsPath, $"output_{currentTime}.wav");

    // Create the wave file writer to save the audio stream
    _writer = new WaveFileWriter(filename, new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2));

    try
    {
        var buffer = new byte[81920]; // Buffer size can be adjusted as needed

        while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, _cts.Token);

            // If bytesRead is zero, end of the stream has been reached
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                continue;
            }

            // Write from buffer to wave file
            await _writer.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Flush the writer to ensure data is written to disk
            await _writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        Logger.Output($"Audio processing was cancelled. {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}", Logger.LogType.Error);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        Logger.Output($"Audio processing timed out. {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}", Logger.LogType.Error);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        Logger.Output($"Audio processing failed due to stream issue. {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}",
            Logger.LogType.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Output($"Audio processing failed. {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}", Logger.LogType.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        await inputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}

The problem seems to be in this line "var bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, _cts.Token);" the function is called but never returns. It seems the stream never contains any data.
Is there a possible solution for this in C# or Python?
Thank you very much!

If you are comfortable switching libraries, pycord has a functional audio sink feature (https://guide.pycord.dev/voice/receiving), but it requires a bit of code rewriting.
However, discord.py extension libraries have been created that allow voice channels to be used as sinks. They can automatically save audio to .wav and .mp3 files on-demand. See discord-ext-voice-recv for more information.
